# Web Crawler Engine used by Kentico 10

Tags: web-crawler, kentico

Is there more information available about the web crawler technology/engine used by Kentico 10 as per documentation [Configuring Page Crawler Indexes](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/creating-search-indexes/defining-page-indexes#Definingpageindexes-Configuringpagecrawlerindexes)?

The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to consider it for use in a custom crawler project that can sit outside of Kentico, and still allow for it to have an inherent compatibility with the Kentico platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the Kentico 10 source code, the crawler used by Kentico SmartSearch is completely proprietary. It's not using any 3rd party library.

It downloads the page content using `System.Web.HttpWebRequest`. The full content is fed back into the SmartSearch indexer as a string. After that it goes through text extraction and is fed to Lucene for indexing.

It's not going to be easy to have Kentico SmartSearch use an external crawler. We usually stay away from the crawler because it is rather expensive to execute compared to the standard index that pulls data straight from the database.

Kentico supports [executing some scheduled tasks in a Windows service](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/scheduling-tasks/configuring-scheduled-task-execution) but not the search tasks.

Note that Kentico SmartSearch doesn't actually crawl the site by discovering links. It uses the content tree to figure out what content it needs to index. If you want to index other content, for example from a system you integrate with, you need to implement a custom search service as described [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/smart-search-api-and-customization/creating-custom-smart-search-indexes).

One thing that would work is to have an external process crawl whatever content you want to index and put the raw HTML content into storage. Then write a custom SmartSearch index that pulls the data from storage for indexing within Kentico. If you're indexing content managed by Kentico, you could take that to the next level by hooking into document events. That should allow you to crawl pages only when they're updated.

Answer (score -1):

Kentico uses [Lucene .NET](https://lucenenet.apache.org/). It's a great solution for stand-alone projects. I used it to power a custom web API hosted in Azure.

Mike

Comment: Kentico search is called SmartSearch and uses Lucene as the search engine but the question asks what web crawler Kentico uses. AFAIK Lucene can't crawl pages.

Answer (score -1):

Lucene uses Nutch http://nutch.apache.org/ which is an open source web crawler to index web content. It's part of the entire framework that lucene offers.

Comment: Lucene does not use Nutch but Nutch used to use Lucene.

Comment: Your link doesn't verify that. However, it answers your question that Nutch is web crawler which is used within Nutch, Lucen and Solr landscape. However I answered your original question correctly. You're free to down vote it.  https://groups.drupal.org/lucene-nutch-and-solr

Comment: In reference to the original question, can you prove that Kentico 10 uses Nutch to crawl?